# Javascript setTimeout inside setInterval

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a problem here.. 
I use a `setInterval` function to load a page into a div, once every 30 seconds. Well.. in that page I have another `setInterval` function, which consists of a countdown that change a number every second.
The problem is that at a time, the countdown jumps over 3 seconds, even if it must callback in one second.
It's like : 01:24 -> 01:21 -> 01->19...

Here is the code for my first setinterval:

```
<script>
    var t;
    t=setInterval(function(){
        $.get('<?=return_url("php/home_new.php");?>', { k: "1" } ).done(function(data){
            if(data)$("#ex_start_test").html(data);});
        },
        30000
    );
</script>
```

and the code for countdown:

```
<?
$query=q_return("SELECT nume, cod, data, MINUTE(data_start) as minute, data_start FROM chestionare WHERE data_start>date_sub(now(), interval 2 minute)");?>

<script>
    var timp_c="<?=$query['minute'];?>";
    var sec;
    var min;
    $.get('<?=return_url("php/getimp.php");?>', { k: "sec" } ).done(function(data){sec=data;});
    $.get('<?=return_url("php/getimp.php");?>', { k: "min" } ).done(function(data){min=data;});

    setTimeout(refresh, 1000);

    function refresh(){
        if(sec>=1){
            sec=sec-1; 
        }else{
            min=min-1;
            sec=59;
        }

        if(sec<10){
            $("span#ex_start_timp_ramas_sec").each(function(){
                $(this).html("0"+sec);
            });
        }else{
            $("span#ex_start_timp_ramas_sec").each(function(){
                $(this).html(sec);
            });
        }
               $("span#ex_start_timp_ramas_min").each(function(){
            $(this).html(min);
        });

        if(sec==0 && min==0){
            //$("#ex_click_final").trigger('click');
            clearInterval(t);
            $("#ex_new_test").hide();
        }

        setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: what returns getimp.php, actual min-sec? will be more consistent with only one $.get() call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is that each time you reload your page with `setInterval` you are spawning another `setTimeout` chain, without clearing the previous one.

Try saving your `timeoutId` and clearing it as the first thing in your countdown code. Something like this should work:

```
<?
$query=q_return("SELECT nume, cod, data, MINUTE(data_start) as minute, data_start FROM chestionare WHERE data_start>date_sub(now(), interval 2 minute)");?>

<script>
var timp_c="<?=$query['minute'];?>";
     var sec,
         min,
         timeoutId;
     $.get('<?=return_url("php/getimp.php");?>', { k: "sec" } ).done(function(data){sec=data;});
     $.get('<?=return_url("php/getimp.php");?>', { k: "min" } ).done(function(data){min=data;});

     if (timeoutId) {
         clearTimout(timeoutId);
     }

     timeoutId = setTimeout(refresh, 1000);

     function refresh(){
         if(sec>=1){
             sec=sec-1; 
         }else{
             min=min-1;
             sec=59;
         }

         if(sec<10){
             $("span#ex_start_timp_ramas_sec").each(function(){
                 $(this).html("0"+sec);
             });
         }else{
             $("span#ex_start_timp_ramas_sec").each(function(){
                 $(this).html(sec);
             });
         }

         $("span#ex_start_timp_ramas_min").each(function(){
             $(this).html(min);
         });

         if(sec==0 && min==0){
             //$("#ex_click_final").trigger('click');
             clearInterval(t);
             $("#ex_new_test").hide();
         }

         timeoutId = setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you make two Ajax requests and afterwards you want to start the timer, but those requests take time to execute because they're asynchronous, which would explain the results you're seeing.

`$.when()` to the rescue:

```
var $getsec = $.get('<?=return_url("php/getimp.php");?>', { k: "sec" } ),
$getmin = $.get('<?=return_url("php/getimp.php");?>', { k: "min" } );

$.when($getsec, $getmin).done(function($sec, $min) {
    min = $min[0]; // [0] = data
    sec = $sec[0];
    // start refresh
    setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
});
```